# error when i print a table

Tags: javascript, css

i recreated the problem on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k1p8Lrez/)
like you can see the table is show without problem but as soon u press on the "stampa" button the line 12 have the text outside the table
i don't understand why is different when the css for the view and the print is the same
i use this code from 2 years and is the first time i got this problem, if you try to delete a row you don't have anymore the problem (but this isn't a fix for me :-P )

how i can solve it?

```
@media print{\
      @page {size: landscape;}\
        table { width:100%; height:100%; font-size: 120%; text-align:center }\
        td.mattina { vertical-align: top; }\
        td.pomeriggio { vertical-align: bottom; }\
        div.mattina { background-color:Aquamarine; -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; }\
        div.pomeriggio { background-color:khaki; -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;  }\
        .color1 { background-color:orangered; -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;  }\
        #ad{ display:none;}\
        #leftbar{ display:none;}\
        #contentarea{ width:100%;}\
        }\
```

**edit**
[image: error]

Comment: Can you elaborate your question more. You mean row 12 breaks to two pages when you take print ?

Comment: @AfnanNazir added the screen of the error

Comment: What browser? Your jfiddle works okay on Chrome, even when I click "stampa" to print.

Comment: i use chrome (tried on 2 computer both with chrome) same error... maybe is windows 10 fault?

Comment: I have also tried your fiddle in FF and Chrome and I can not reproduce this error. If YOU use the same fiddle with Chrome you will get this error??? Or you are getting the error on your site?

Comment: @Franco yes with my browser on fiddle i have the problem on both the computer, i use chrome 53.0.2785.143 m (64-bit)  
i tried on a 3rd computer and i still have that problem... maybe is something OS oriented or maybe language bug?

Comment: You are just printing a page from the view and probably the last row do not fit the page anymore. If the table become more and more bigger than you will have more problems. You should create a `pdf` and let the user download it.